# How to change a cell with a button in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bGjDrQ5jsqRMnv9dIvpa5HYhJ3ndRhqTl955NBP2j-s/htmlview#

So here’s my question. is there a way to enter the bin number and enter the PO number (in cell A3 and B3) and have a button run the app script so that it can replace the PO number in the right spot.

Bin # B10 had PO # 472747. I want to be able to type B10 in cell A3 and a new number in cell B3 and it will change the PO number to the new number for B10.

I would really like a button to press to make the process easy

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the button and just use a script called whenever an edit is made, watching for B3.

```
function onEdit(e){
 if (!e) throw "Do not run from editor";

 replacePO(e);
}

function replacePO(e){
 const r = e.range;
 const bin = r.offset(0,-1).getValue()
 if (bin.length == 0 || r.getA1Notation() != "B3") return;

 const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
 let bins = src.getRange(4,1,src.getLastRow()).getValues();
 for (let i in bins){
  if (bins[i][0] == bin){
   src.getRange(+i+4,2).setValue(e.value);
   r.offset(0,-1,1,2).clearContent();
   return;
  }
 }
}
```

This should be right, but since your sheet is set to view only I couldn't directly test.

Comment: it is on edit mode now. I would like a button so that others will find it easier.

Comment: I would advise against a button. This runs every time an edit is made to B3 so your users don't even need to find anything. Additionally, buttons can be obtrusive to the rest of the sheet, require user authentication, AND cannot be used on mobile devices. If you insist on having the user do something, rather than just an edit (but the edit is the easiest, simplest, most intuitive thing) then we can put a checkbox for the user to click.

Comment: okay no button is fine. How do I get the script to run? I think i put it int the right spot but im not sure. Thanks so much for you help

Comment: Go to the script editor and paste this in. That's it. It runs whenever you edit B3 so long as there is a valid BIN# in A3.

Comment: Thanks it works!! One small things i would like to add. Is there a way to delete A3 and B3 once it has updated. What i tested was that when I delete the po# it updates to blank, if that makes sense

Comment: Yes, see the updated script where I call r.offset(0,-1,1,2).clearContent();